# Cannot iterate through array

Tags: java, twitter-oauth

```
UserType statuses = twitter.getFriendsStatuses(UserType.class, null, null);
for( UserType  users :  statuses )
{
     out.println("<p>"+users.getName()+"</p>");
}
```

I get an error "Foreach not applicable to expression type".

---

my methods definition is this:

```
public <T> T getFriendsStatuses(Class<T> responseType, String lite, String page) throws UniformInterfaceException {
        String[] queryParamNames = new String[]{"lite", "page"};
        String[] queryParamValues = new String[]{lite, page};
        return webResource.queryParams(getQueryOrFormParams(queryParamNames, queryParamValues)).accept(javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType.TEXT_XML).get(responseType);
    }
```

Comment: Is there a typo in your code? Because `statuses` is _not_ an array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is because `UserType` does not implement [`Iterable<T>`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html). Thus, you can not use the enhanced `for` (*foreach*) loop to iterate over it.

---

**EDIT**: Given the example you provided, my wild [guess](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/websvc/twitter-swing.html) is that the code was generated by Jersey. If that is the case, then you should be using `Statuses.class` instead of `UserType.class`. Then, you can get a `List` of `StatusType`, which you can then use in the `for` loop, since `List` implements `Iterable`.

```
Statuses statuses = twitter.getFriendsStatuses(Statuses.class, null, null); 
for (StatusType statusType : statuses.getStatus()) {
  UserType userType = statusType.getUser();
  System.out.println("<p>" + userType.getName() + "</p>");
}
```

But then again, it is just a wild guess.

Comment: This is what i get:unexpected element (uri:"", local:"users"). Expected elements are <{}statuses> The thing is that Statuses returns this:   public List<StatusType> getStatus() {
        if (status == null) {
            status = new ArrayList<StatusType>();
        }
        return this.status;
    }

Answer (score 0):

Does UserType implement Collection or Iterable?

You can only apply for each to collections or arrays (or anything implementing Iterable).

http://leepoint.net/notes-java/flow/loops/foreach.html